# Is it possible to find a solution to the following $(x(b+x) + c - f) \mod (2x+2) = 0$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratics

Given the equation 
$$
(x(b+x) + c - f) \mod (2x+2) = 0
$$
Is it possible and if so what is the quickest way to find appropriate value of $x$? Where $x > 0$

The above equation is derived from the following two quadratic equations
$$ax^2+bx+c$$
$$dx^2+ex+f$$

example equations are
$$x^2 + 27305078x + 20664318$$
$$x^2 + 27305076x + 186391793841444$$

resulting in $$(x(27305078+x) + 20664318 - 186391793841444) \mod (2x+2) = 0$$

All of the above is from an encryption/decryption scheme I am toying with so the example equations are trivial and the answer is found easily by iterative means but for non trivial equations iteration is too computationally expensive.

Comment: Well, just for starters, you can replace $c-f$ by a single name, say $d$, to get $$(x^2 + bx + d) \bmod (2x +2) = 0.$$ Then replacing $x+1$ by $y$, you get $$y^2 -2y + 1 + by - b + d \bmod 2y = 0,$$ which has the general form $$y^2 + b'y + c' \bmod 2y = 0,$$ which is  a little easier to look at. And then you see that $y$ must be a factor of $c'$, so you need only check factors of $c'$ rather than all possible numbers. Of course, *finding* factors of $c'$ may be difficult in general. :)

Comment: Thanks john, please excuse my ignorance.I am not familiar with the notation $b'y$ does the apostrophe have a special meaning in this context? what happened to the $-2y+1$ in the general form?

Comment: I just worked through an example and using $c'=-b+d+1$ arrived back at my initial starting point of $c'=186391800482203$. which is computationally infeasible to factor in non trivial cases. so it seems this line of inquiry may be a bust

Comment: It just meant "we can reduce the thing above to $y^2 + (b-2)y + (1-b+d)$, and then use new names to replace the coefficients, i.e., we can use new variables --- I've called them $b'$ -- defined by $b' = b-2$, and $c' = 1 - b + d$ -- to make the expression look simpler: it's just an ordinary quadratic. If you know $b$ and $d$, you can find $b'$ and $d'$; if you know $b'$ and $d'$, you can find $b$ and $d$...so there's no magic here; just visual simplicity. And of course you end up back at the same *computational* problem --- that's the idea. But it's easier to look at.

Comment: As for "which is computationally infeasible to factor...", in your earlier description you suggested that you were using "iterative means," which sounded to me like trying sequential values of $x$, not "trying to factor something." Anyhow, comments are generally intended as a place to clarify/simplify questions, not to answer them. If you don't think my simplification's actually simpler, so be it. As for actually *solving* the problem...I've got nothing. I don't do much algebra/number theory, so I have no instant insights.

Comment: Your simplification proved to me that all I was doing was rephrasing the original problem, not actually coming up with an alternate method to solve the problem. The reference to an iterative approach (slightly more optimised than simply trying different x's) was only for very simple problems. Many thanks for your assistance.